# eclipse project has jar in referenced library not listed as dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a java project setup in eclipse to build with maven. Project itself is a multi-module maven project (but I am not using m2e plugin rather maven-eclipse plugin, and eclipse project does not have maven nature)

When running mvn install within eclipse, everything compiles fine, but when I run the same command in command prompt, I get compile errors due to a missing dependency.

I see that the jar it's looking for is neither listed explicitly as dependency in pom.xml or is a transitive dependency. I tried running mvn dependency:tree but also couldn't see this jar.

How can this jar be available in eclipse?

Update: two missing jars are

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-jms</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Check the .m2 repository location in your eclipse. window>preference>maven>usersettings

Comment: I checked and repository location pointed to the correct location

Comment: post up the pom or the name of the jar. you might receive some more support :)

Comment: The maven-eclipse-plugin is long deprecated - don't expect it to work with any recent eclipse version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. Problem had to do with my invalid global mirror settings that redirected traffic to wrong remote repository so it could not find and install dependencies, later causing compile error.

In eclipse, I was using embedded maven referencing user settings only with no global settings therefore it worked fine.